# DAX- Column look up

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, business-intelligence

I have a single table with columns End_Of_Month, ID.

[image]

**What I am trying to achieve:** I want to know which IDs in 3/31/2021 **did not** occurr in the next month_end_date.

As an example: 2 IDs(ID 3 & ID 4) mentioned in 31/3/2021 did not appear in the next calendar month_end_date.

Comment: Do you want a measure or a calculated column? is the end result limited to only finding about 3/31?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have assumed you want to show a measure against each `End_Of_Month` value.
The result is a concatenation of the missing `ID` separated by a comma.

### Calculation: Measure

```
MissingIds =
VAR CurrentMonth =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[End_Of_Month] )
VAR NextMth =
    EOMONTH ( CurrentMonth, 1 )
VAR AllIds =
    SUMMARIZE ( FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), [End_Of_Month] = NextMth ), [ID] )
VAR CurrentIds =
    VALUES ( 'Table'[ID] )
VAR MissingIds =
    EXCEPT ( CurrentIds, AllIds )
VAR Result =
    CONCATENATEX ( MissingIds, [ID], "," )
RETURN
    IF ( ISEMPTY ( AllIds ), BLANK (), Result )
```

### Output

[image]

### Table

| End_Of_Month | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 31 March 2021 | 1 |
| 30 April 2021 | 1 |
| 31 May 2021 | 1 |
| 31 March 2021 | 2 |
| 30 April 2021 | 2 |
| 31 May 2021 | 2 |
| 31 March 2021 | 3 |
| 31 May 2021 | 3 |
| 31 May 2021 | 3 |
| 31 March 2021 | 4 |
| 30 April 2021 | 7 |
| 30 April 2021 | 8 |
| 30 April 2021 | 9 |

### Edit:

I have modified the calculation to account for any dates, instead of End of Month (EOM).
Please see the table below as a reference.

```
MissingIds =
VAR CurrentDate =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[Date] )
VAR NextDt =
    MINX ( FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), [Date] > CurrentDate ), [Date] )
VAR AllIds =
    SUMMARIZE ( FILTER ( ALL ( 'Table' ), [Date] = NextDt ), [ID] )
VAR CurrentIds =
    VALUES ( 'Table'[ID] )
VAR MissingIds =
    EXCEPT ( CurrentIds, AllIds )
VAR Result =
    CONCATENATEX ( MissingIds, [ID], "," )
RETURN
    IF ( ISEMPTY ( AllIds ), BLANK (), Result )
```

### Ouput

[image]

### Table

| Date | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 15 January 2021 | 1 |
| 15 January 2021 | 2 |
| 15 January 2021 | 3 |
| 18 January 2021 | 2 |
| 18 January 2021 | 2 |
| 18 January 2021 | 5 |
| 22 January 2021 | 7 |
| 22 January 2021 | 7 |
| 22 January 2021 | 5 |

Comment: Thanks a lot @Angelo. This works. Also what I wanted to know was, if I was supposed to tweek this logic to show daily dates instead of End Of the month, how would it work? I tried making changes to the logic but I keep getting error.
Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Hi, Is it possible you can mark the answer as a solution?  The code is a bit different going by dates instead of Months.

Comment: This solution was certainly helpful when considering EOM. I was working into the by date dax which aggregates the count of missing IDs by date instead of EOM and it keeps throwing error. Is that something you can help with?

Comment: I've added the calculation for any date using similar logic.

Comment: Hi @Angelo, The MissingIDs is suppose to show the count of missing items rather than the list. For some reason the date list does not seem to work for me.

Comment: On the `VAR RESULT` you can change `CONCATENATEX` for `COUNTROWS`. That would give you the number of IDs.

Answer (score 0):

This solution works well for cases where there is data till end of next months but for situations where data is till middle of the month, it gives 0. How can that be fixed?

As an example:

[image]

I want the calculation to also show ids missing between period 30th April to 14th May.

Comment: Can you create a separate question with representative sample data? Also, can you include the code you have tried?

Comment: Hi Angelo, I am basically trying to apply a SQL logic in Dax. I have added it as a new question. The link to the new post is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67571092/inner-join-sql-to-dax-conversion
Would really appreciate if you could guide on the same.