# INNER JOIN SQL to DAX Conversion

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, business-intelligence

I am trying to write a DAX equivalent for the below SQL Query below:

```
Select sum(a.CountOfEIN), a.Date1
from (
SELECT tab1.Date1, Count(tab1.EID) AS CountOfID
FROM Tab1 
INNER JOIN Tab1 AS Tab2 
ON Tab1.EID = Tab2.EID
WHERE (((Tab1.STATUS)<>"D") AND ((Tab2.STATUS)="D") AND ((Tab1.ACTIVE)=1))
GROUP BY Tab1.Date1, Tab2.Date1
HAVING (((Tab1.Date1)>='2021-02-01') AND ((Tab2.Date1)=[Tab1].[Date1]+1))
) a 
group by a.Date1
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use NATURALINNERJOIN, also when you ask questions make sure you provide sample data and the expected result.

Comment: what do you want to achive? New Table or measure?

Comment: I need to write a measure for the above SQL statement.